# Possible reflection Issues with type-graphql mutations?

Tags: typescript, graphql, typegraphql

I've been trying to use `type-graphql` in a recent nodejs project. I've been able to successfully implement `@Query` methods but can't for the life of me get the following to work. I'm using this with Moleculer service.

```
@Mutation()
  // eslint-disable-next-line class-methods-use-this
  removeValue((@Arg("value") value: number): void {
    console.log(value);
  }
```

I get the following errors

```
/home/micro-api/node_modules/type-graphql/dist/helpers/findType.js:10
 metadataDesignType = reflectedType[parameterIndex];
                                          ^
/home/micro-api/node_modules/type-graphql/dist/helpers/findType.js:1
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Any ideas ? I've seen some comments mentioning reflection in my searches but as I'm fairly new to node and typescript i'm a bit stuck.

Comment: Did you go step by step the official setup instruction?
https://typegraphql.com/docs/next/installation.html
Do you use babel? If yes, do you have proper typescript and reflection related plugins?

Answer (score 0):

I think that The problem that you are facing is that a Mutation (or Query) should not return anything nor `void`. Please check https://github.com/MichalLytek/type-graphql/issues/318

A simple patch could be:

```
@Mutation(() => Boolean)  
removeValue((@Arg("value") value: number): boolean {
    console.log(value);
    return true;
}
```